# Is the list order of a ConcurrentDictionary guaranteed?

Tags: .net, list, concurrency, concurrentdictionary, blockingcollection

I am using a ConcurrentDictionary to store log-lines, and when I need to display them to the user I call `ToList()` to generate a list. But the weird thing is that some users receive the most recent lines first in the list, while they should logically be last.

Is this because ConcurrentDictionary doesnt guarantee a persistent order on the IEnumerate interface, or what can be the reason?

Comment: Sort by the a DateTime value when displaying the data.

Comment: @usr I was planning on doing that, but its sort of a workaround. Id like to understand why it happens first.

Comment: Related: [Is ConcurrentDictionary always add item by order in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75226870/is-concurrentdictionary-always-add-item-by-thread-order-in-c)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No `ConcurrentDictionary` (and `Dictionary<T>` for that matter) does not guarantee the ordering of the keys in the list.  You'll have to use a different data type or perform the sorting yourself.  For non-concurrent code you would use [`SortedDictionary<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but I don't believe there is an analogue in the concurrent collections.

Answer (score 4):

No. The list order of ConcurrentDictionary is NOT guaranteed, lines can come out in any order.