# Is ConcurrentDictionary.TryAdd() result in an order following the calling order?

Tags: c#, concurrency, ordereddictionary, concurrentdictionary

I have tested in a multithreaded scenario, seems the key-value pairs added by `TryAdd()` method is randomly ordered, even with adequate interval for the Adding action to complete. Sometime new item was added to the beginning, sometime at the end.

How can i make sure `Tryadd()` adds items in calling order?

Comment: Dictionaries and Sorting don't fit well. Dictionaries are hash based and at best sorted by that. It isn't a simple List internally where something get added to the end. If you need sorting i assume you have todo it explicitly yourself.

Comment: And if that sorting relies on when it has been added to the dictionary i assume you have to add a timestamp to the data.

Comment: It was told that ConcurrentDictionary is a good replacement for List under multihtreading scenario, now it seems it is not?

Comment: A dictionary is something else then a list. so they have different features. You don't need fast access by a key? Then don't use a dictionary.

Comment: sadly I need both Order and Fast access.

Comment: But you were comparing to List<T>. That also don't have fast key access.

Comment: Orderby is a choice, but not quite ideal by performance.

Comment: I just mentioned that someone said if u want a List under multithreads, use but ConccurentDictionary. now i know it's not pefectly that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244500/discussion-between-xiaoyuvax-and-ralf).

Comment: Related: [Is the list order of a ConcurrentDictionary guaranteed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20020074/is-the-list-order-of-a-concurrentdictionary-guaranteed)

Comment: Re, "I need both Order and Fast access." Sometimes, you need more than one data structure. Is there a reason why you can't add the same items to both a dictionary _and_ a list?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @SolomonSlow it's a better solution than timestamp i feel.

Comment: @SolomonSlow But sadly i later finally found timestamp is better or maybe the only working solution in my case. lol but i will remember ur suggestion.